# Is it possible to make a OR in a MATCH or to do something equivalent?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to applying some access checks on some objects.
We defined several ways to get access to an object. Here are 4 of them :

- user is directly assigned to the object
- user is assigned to a child (or child of child) of the object
- object's org unit is a child of the user's org unit (we have a org unit tree)
- child's org unit is a child of the user's org unit

Currently, I am using this query (the object type queried is an ActionPlan and the child type is Task):

```
//Access via AP org unit
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:4321" )
MATCH (ap:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
MATCH p=(user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT]->(u_ou)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]-> (ap_ou)<-[:ORG_UNIT]-(ap)
RETURN ap

//Access via Task org unit
UNION
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:4321" )
MATCH (ap:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
MATCH p=(user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT]->(u_ou)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]-> (t_ou)<-[:ORG_UNIT]-(t:Task)<-[:PARENT_OF*1..2]-(ap)
RETURN ap

//Access via AP direct assignment
UNION 
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:4321" )
MATCH (ap:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
MATCH p=(user)<-[:ASSIGNED_USER]-(ap) 
RETURN ap

//Access via Task direct assignment
UNION
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:4321" )
MATCH (ap:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
MATCH p=(user)<-[:ASSIGNED_USER]-(t:Task)<-[:PARENT_OF*1..2]-(ap)
RETURN ap
```

I am able to get the correct result but I have to repeat myself a lot and I cannot use LIMIT for paginating the results (see  https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725).

I tried using OPTIONAL MATCH. I get the correct result, but I still have a lot of duplication and poorer performance than with UNION :

```
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:4321" )
OPTIONAL MATCH accessViaOuAP=(user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT]->(u_ou1)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]->(ap_ou)<-[:ORG_UNIT]-(ap1:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap1.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
OPTIONAL MATCH accessViaOuTask=(user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT]->(u_ou)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]-> (t_ou)<-[:ORG_UNIT]-(t1:Task)<-[:PARENT_OF*1..2]-(ap2:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap2.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
OPTIONAL MATCH apAssignement = (user)<-[:ASSIGNED_USER]-(ap3:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap3.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
OPTIONAL MATCH taskAssignement = (user)<-[:ASSIGNED_USER]-(t2:Task)<-[:PARENT_OF*1..2]-(ap4:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap4.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
RETURN ap1,ap2,ap3,ap4
```

Moreover, I do not like the RETURN in this query.

I was wondering if there is a way to write the query more or less like this :

```
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:4321" )
MATCH (ap:ActionPlan)
WHERE ap.name CONTAINS "ipsum"
MATCH (user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT]->(u_ou)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]-> (ap_ou)<-[:ORG_UNIT]-(ap)
    OR (user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT]->(u_ou)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]-> (t_ou)<-[:ORG_UNIT]-(t:Task)<-[:PARENT_OF*1..2]-(ap)
    OR (user)<-[:ASSIGNED_USER]-(ap) 
    OR (user)<-[:ASSIGNED_USER]-(t:Task)<-[:PARENT_OF*1..2]-(ap)
RETURN ap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the patterns in the WHERE was not the solution. It created a huge performance issue : from 100ms to more than 20s.

I decided to change the relations of my model and I know have a generic access check query that I can apply to all my object types :

```
START user=node:UserIndex( "id:8978" )
MATCH p=(user)-[:ASSIGNED_TO_ORG_UNIT|:PARENT_OF|:ORG_UNIT_OF|:ASSIGNED_TO|:CHILD_OF_OBJ*]->(obj)
WHERE obj.name CONTAINS "ipsum" 
RETURN obj
```

Then, depending on the query I want to make I can specify the Label to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you define by `more or less` is possible, exactly as you wrote.

Example based on the default graph at http://console.neo4j.org

```
MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE (n)-[:KNOWS]->(:Matrix) 
OR (n)-[:LOVES]->(:Crew) 
RETURN n
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I tried this, but the problem is the performance. With the UNION or the OPTIONAL, I get the result in 100ms. With the patterns in the WHERE, I have to wait more than 20 seconds.